# Invalid cloud-config provided, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, openstack, cloud-init

G-day!
I'm trying to prepare an image for openstack. But I'm getting an error.
cloud-init-output.log:

```
2022-08-08 20:01:34,225 - schema.py[WARNING]: Invalid cloud-config provided: Please run 'sudo cloud-init schema --system' to see the schema errors.
Cloud-init v. 22.2-0ubuntu1~22.04.3 running 'modules:config' at Mon, 08 Aug 2022 20:01:36 +0000. Up 12.47 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 22.2-0ubuntu1~22.04.3 running 'modules:final' at Mon, 08 Aug 2022 20:01:36 +0000. Up 13.04 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 22.2-0ubuntu1~22.04.3 finished at Mon, 08 Aug 2022 20:01:36 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNone.  Up 13.27 seconds
2022-08-08 20:01:37,016 - cc_final_message.py[WARNING]: Used fallback datasource
```

sudo cloud-init schema --system

```
Error:
Cloud config schema errors: users.0: {'gecos': 'cadm', 'groups': {'plugdev', 'sudo', 'lxd', 'adm', 'dip', 'cdrom'}, 'lock_passwd': False, 'name': 'cadm', 'passwd': '$6$QJhQO5wtDW8P7hgm$5xsTlX9WZsY8ksqYbWmltQP3boAprZFQUb2wBqNWPAH9XyPcuDGa8dtjORG7O7enQ2pwWHuhcag0SwedvstvV0', 'shell': '/bin/bash'} is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

systemctl status cloud-init:

```
● cloud-init.service - Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cloud-init.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2022-08-08 20:01:34 UTC; 15min ago
   Main PID: 593 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 761ms

Aug 08 20:01:34 ubuntu cloud-init[597]: ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++Route IPv6 info+++++++++++++++++++
Aug 08 20:01:34 ubuntu cloud-init[597]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
Aug 08 20:01:34 ubuntu cloud-init[597]: ci-info: | Route | Destination | Gateway | Interface | Flags |
Aug 08 20:01:34 ubuntu cloud-init[597]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
Aug 08 20:01:34 ubuntu cloud-init[597]: ci-info: |   1   |  fe80::/64  |    ::   |   enp1s0  |   U   |
Aug 08 20:01:34 ubuntu cloud-init[597]: ci-info: |   3   |    local    |    ::   |   enp1s0  |   U   |
Aug 08 20:01:34 ubuntu cloud-init[597]: ci-info: |   4   |  multicast  |    ::   |   enp1s0  |   U   |
Aug 08 20:01:34 ubuntu cloud-init[597]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
Aug 08 20:01:34 ubuntu cloud-init[597]: 2022-08-08 20:01:34,225 - schema.py[WARNING]: Invalid cloud-config provided: Please run 'sudo cloud-init schema --system' to see the schema errors.
Aug 08 20:01:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler).
```

I'm using regular cloud-init in Ubuntu 22.04 image, I make small changes in the following lines:

```
# If this is set, 'root' will not be able to ssh in and they
# will get a message to login instead as the default $user
disable_root: false
ssh_pwauth: true

   # Default user name + that default users groups (if added/used)
   default_user:
     name: cadm
     lock_passwd: False
```

After installing the image on the open stack, network interfaces do not work (down), the ssx service crashes with errors, the user is not created, the hostname does not change, and many more problems... Please tell me how to solve this problem?
Thank you all and have a nice day!

Comment: I had the same problem as you All due to a mount point I had added for a backup disk.. This led to the error I modified /etc/fstab and i comment the line with my backup hard disk, rebooted and this worked for me

Comment: I have the exact same problem after apt upgrade and reboot of my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server. `… Cloud config schema errors: users.0: …` Meanwhile a found the reason for my problem. I had an old entry in `/etc/fstab` that was pointing to a device, that is not currently present. Removing that entry solved my problem. So the reason was actually unrelated to what the error was pointing at.

Comment: Just went through the same issue in 22.04. It was about broken USB hard drive for backups, but happened right after reboot after apt upgrade.